How to listen to an event triggered from my lwc in an aura application
I am trying to trigger an event from my lwc based on which I need to conditionally render some components inside my aura application. My application is independent of any other aura components and we have only lwc's. Since the components that I am trying to render has some aura dependency, I had to add these components directly in my aura application. When I add these components directly in my aura application it is rendering fine. Now my goal is to render these by listening to an event triggered from my lwc.
This is what I am doing currently from my lwc (this is getting triggered without any issues)
handleCheckboxChange() {
        const filterChangeEvent = new CustomEvent('togglecomponent', {
            detail: { flag: true }
            bubbles: true, // Ensure the event bubbles up to the Aura component
            composed: true // Ensure the event crosses the shadow DOM boundary
        });
        // Fire the custom event
        this.dispatchEvent(filterChangeEvent);
    }

Now this is what I am currently doing in my aura application.
<module_name:lwcname name="test" ontogglecomponent="{!c.handleCustomEvent}"/>

I added a new function in my aura controller js file with the name handleCustomEvent. But it doesn't seem to be hitting when the event is triggered from my lwc. Does anyone know what else I should be doing?

According to Send Events to an Enclosing Aura Component, this should work (you don't even need bubbles/composed, apparently). You may have oversimplified your problem? Perhaps you could add some more detail surrounding the events? Something we could copy-paste into our own orgs verbatim that demonstrate the problem?

Yes that's what I tried to do initially, but it doesn't seem to be working. I am wondering if the event is not getting passed higher up the dom tree.
